# Should these 2 code blocks be equivalent? (assignment in an if)

Tags: dart

Should the following two code blocks be equivalent? My intuition says yes, but they produce different behaviors.

The first code block works the way I expect, the second does not. I really want to use the second style, because it makes the actual code (some of which was omitted here) much shorter and easier on the eye.

```dart
if (expanding) {
  radius += delta;
  if (radius > maxRadius)
    expanding = false;
} else {
  radius -= delta;
  if (radius < minRadius)
    expanding = true;
}
```

versus

```dart
if (expanding && (radius += delta) > maxRadius) {
  expanding = false;
} else if ((radius -= delta) < minRadius) {
   expanding = true;
}
```

Comment: No.  Because, y'know, different behaviors.  FWIW the first style is clearer.  It's fairly poor style to mix your metaphors like that, regardless of any brevity that might be gained.

Comment: Part of the reason they're not equivalent is because the second style uses the return value of the expressions `(radius += delta)` and `(radius -= delta)`, whereas the first style does not.  It's entirely possible that you're getting returned the value of radius *prior* to the increment or decrement.

Comment: Yes, *prior to the increment or decrement.*  Unless you break out your language reference to verify the behavior, there's no way to know for sure. Except maybe breaking out a debugger. Or saying `someValue = (radius += delta)` and examining the values of `someValue` and `radius`.

Comment: Well, those aren't the same operators, but that's the basic principle, yes.  `a++` will return the original value for `a`, *pre-increment*.  `++a`, on the other hand, will increment *first*, and then return the new value for `a`.  You'll have to figure out whether `+=` returns the *pre* or *post* value.  Do you see now why I favor the first version? :)

Comment: Re "prior to the increment or decrement": `int a = 3; print(a += 1);` prints 4, so it seems `+=` returns the value _after_ the increment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `expanding` is `true` but `radius + delta <= maxRadius`, the first version increments `radius` by `delta` and is done; the second version increments `radius` by `delta` then fails the first conditional and then decrements `radius` by `delta`, leaving it where it started.

So: No, the two blocks should not be expected to behave the same way.  Even if you added `! expanding &&` to the `else` conditional, the first version is *much* clearer, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain why the second version fails the conditional?

Comment: The second version contains a `&&` (a conditional AND).  `(radius += delta)` should not execute if `expanding` is `false`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, the case I'm talking about is when `expanding` is `true`.

Comment: @Ganymede if `expanding` is `true` and `radius + delta <= maxRadius`, then `(radius += delta) > maxRadius)` would evaluate to `false`, sending you to the `else` conditional (where `radius` is decremented).

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
radius += expanding ? delta : -delta;
if (expanding && radius > maxRadius)
   expanding = false;
if (!expanding && radius < minRadius)
   expanding = true;
```

This separates the functions of incrementing the radius and toggling expansion, but still simplifies the code from its original verison.

Comment: Still working on the logic.  But you got the basic idea, right?

Comment: That is good, thanks! I'll do it that way. But the original question is still unanswered

Comment: I have no idea about that.